# invalid value in "less" when comparing np.nan in an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

observe

```
np.nan < 0

False
```

---

```
np.array([np.nan]) < 0

array([False], dtype=bool)
```

---

However

```
np.array([-1, np.nan]) < 0
```

> ```
> //anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
>   if \__name\__ == '\__main\__':
> ```

```
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

What does that error mean?

Comment: Try running those tests again.  ` less if name == 'main':` looks more like an syntax error than a real numpy issue.  Make sure the error is reproducible.

Comment: @hpaulj I'll repost when I get back to a computer. I tested many times. Must be a version of something. I'll include that info or open an issue.

Comment: @hpaulj it's just a matter of formatting which got messed on copy paste to SO. `if __name__ = "__main__"` part comes from ipython way of reporting the warning (`np.less` is on a separate line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only a warning, not an exception. Numpy tries to be helpful and reports that you have a `nan` in your array.  It's safe to ignore it. If the warning itself bothers you (or your users), you can suppress it:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    np.less([np.nan, 0], 1)
```

However, this is really not recommended since it can mask less obvious issues and make debugging harder if you need to find where a `nan` comes from in a lengthy calculation.

Note the semantics of a `nan`: `nan > 0`, `nan < 0` and `nan < nan`, `nan == nan` are all `False`.

Also note that in numpy (unlike e.g. pandas) `nan` really means *invalid* not *not available*.

Comment: nan = not a number