# Why is scipy.stats.ttest_ind throwing a new RuntimeWarning when comparing nans?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, anaconda

I'm working with some pretty huge but sparsely populated pandas DataFrames. I use `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` to make comparisons of some of these columns which contain many nans. I recently updated to Anaconda 4.2.12 and now when use `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` I get the run time error seen in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
case1 = case2 = np.linspace(np.nan,np.nan,5)
scipy.stats.ttest_ind(case1,case2)

>>>output: 
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1748: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
    cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x > self.a) & (x < self.b)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1748: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
    cond1 = (scale > 0) & (x > self.a) & (x < self.b)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1749: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)
```

So the function runs and I can use the output just like before I updated the only difference is now I get this run time warning.

If I drop all of the nans in my DataFrames then `ttest_ind` works just fine. But I don't want to do that because I need to maintain the structure of the 
DataFrames.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there anything that I can do besides just keep on using the function ignoring the warning or writing some kind of hacked up work around function?

Comment: I noticed the same thing and I narrowed it down to this numpy example http://stackoverflow.com/q/40452765/2336654

Comment: Interesting. So do you just suppress the error now?

Comment: I suppress it via using pandas.  `pd.Series([np.nan, -1]) < 1`.  But in my opinion this needs to be worked out.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating with an example? If you make that an answer I'll mark this answered right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do

```
np.array([np.nan, -1]) < 0
```

[image]

However, I can wrap it in a pandas series and let pandas supress the warning

```
pd.Series([np.nan, -1]).lt(0).values

array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just find an option:

```
nan_policy='omit'
```

so try this:

```
t,p = ttest_ind(cls_up['cause_pct'],cls_down['cause_pct'],nan_policy='omit')
```

Hope it can be helpful in your case too!